# Is it possible to configure an install4j service to auto-restart on failure for Linux installers?

Tags: install4j

I have an install4j Linux service that I would like to configure to auto-restart on failure. I see an option in the "Install a Service" action for Windows, but nothing for Linux. Does install4j provide this option or is there a suggested workaround? Essentially I would like the generated .service file in systemd to include `Restart=on-failure`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of install4j 7 there is no such feature. For install4j 8, more flexible support of systemd is planned.

Comment: Would it be possible to accomplish this through a custom script fragment for the time being?

Comment: The custom script fragment is inserted into the launcher script. You would have to generate you own .service file for your use case.